# Finding the index of a matching wildcard in excel

Tags: excel, wildcard, vlookup, excel-match

Given a sheet like so:

```
Sheet 1

Product Name
-----------------
Fancy Shoes
Plain Shoes
Comfy Slippers
Nice Loafers
Pressed Shirt
Tee Shirt
Collared Button-Up
```

and a sheet of wildcards:

```
Sheet 2

Product Wildcard   |   Product Category
---------------------------------------
*Shirt             |   Shirt
*Button-Up         |   Shirt
*Shoes             |   Shoes
*Loafers           |   Shoes
*Slippers          |   Shoes
```

I'm hoping to produce the following:

```
Product Name       |   Product Category
----------------------------------------
Fancy Shoes        |   Shoes
Plain Shoes        |   Shoes
Comfy Slippers     |   Shoes
Nice Loafers       |   Shoes
Pressed Shirt      |   Shirt
Tee Shirt          |   Shirt
Collared Button-Up |   Shirt
```

In other words, can I lookup a category for a product in Sheet 1 that matches a Product Wildcard in Sheet 2?

I've tried to use `VLOOKUP('Sheet 1'!A2, 'Sheet 2'!A2:B6, 2, FALSE)` and `MATCH('Sheet 1'!A2, 'Sheet 2'!A2:A6, 0)`.  Both give me #N/A.  I suspect those functions expect the search text to be the only thing that can be wildcarded and my Product Wildcards are taken literally and not interpreted as wildcards.

I'm wondering if there is another way to do this with built-in Excel functions, or if I'm going to need to write some VBA?

Thanks in advance for help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is an array formula (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5,MATCH(1,MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5,Sheet1!A1,0),0))
```

[image]

You can use "Formulas" > "Evaluate Formula" on the cell containing the formula to see how it's working step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading [here](https://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-and-wildcards/) (specifically the note at the bottom), this seems to not be possible using `VLOOKUP` alone.  If all of your wildcards don't have spaces, you could do it like this: (not an explicit formula, just a list of algorithmic steps)

- Reverse the string, with [something like this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/johannh/2018/02/22/reverse-string-in-excel-using-array-formula-and-without-vba/) (this is an array formula, so Ctrl+Shift+Enter is required to use it)
- Use `FIND` to get the location of the first space in the reversed version, subtracting that from the `LEN` of the string gives you the amount of string before the wildcard bit.
- Use `RIGHT` to truncate the string to the wildcard, and use that with `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 0):

***If*** there are *only* two words in each cell ***and*** the word that determines the category (ex.: Shoes, Slippers, Shirt, etc...) is *always* second, you can use the following `INDEX/MATCH` to get the category:

```
=INDEX('Sheet 2'!B$2:B$6,MATCH(MID('Sheet 1'!A2,FIND(" ",'Sheet 1'!A2)+1,LEN('Sheet 1'!A2)-FIND(" ",'Sheet 1'!A2)),'Sheet 2'!A$2:A$6,0))
```