# Users to groups based on Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

Working on a little project that is supposed to place ADusers in ADgroups based on Excel-file.

Got lost in the *.Split-maze and I am sure there is an easy solution I cannot see just now.

```
USERNAME      : PROG-USER-01
USERGROUP-01  : X
USERGROUP-02  :
USERGROUP-03  : X
USERGROUP-04  :

SUITE-ADMINS  :

USERNAME      : PROG-USER-02
USERGROUP-01  :
USERGROUP-02  :
USERGROUP-03  :
USERGROUP-04  : X

SUITE-ADMINS  :
```

Code:

```
$ExcelPlaceUsers = @(Import-Excel -Path "C:\users_and_relations.xlsx" -WorksheetName 'USERGROUP')
$ePUsernames = $ExcelPlaceUsers.USERNAME

foreach ($ePuser in $ePUsernames){
    #$ePuser #USERNAMES
    $targetCell = $ExcelPlaceUsers.$($i)[$ePuser]

    if ($targetCell -eq 'x') {
                #Output
    }
}
```

Wanted output:

```
PROG-USER-01
USERGROUP-01
USERGROUP-03

PROG-USER-02
USERGROUP-04
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/55854654/4961700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the object returned by `Import-Excel` (I'm using the following module: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.0)
Same code will work with a CSV file using the command `Import-CSV`. This won't require an extra module to be installed.

Change the `Write-Output` to whatever you want to do with the values.

```
$ExcelPlaceUsers = Import-Excel .\test.xlsx -NoHeader

Foreach ($Username in $ExcelPlaceUsers) {
    if ($Username.P2 -and $Username.P2 -ne 'X') {
        Write-Output ' '
        Write-Output $Username.P2
    } elseif ($Username.P2 -eq 'X') {
        Write-Output $Username.P1
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
PROG-USER-01
USERGROUP-01
USERGROUP-03

PROG-USER-02
USERGROUP-04
```

Comment: possible to make it loop? need the code to be more dynamic, lots of users :)

Comment: Appears to work fine when I add more users to the list in the same format. Printscreen: http://prntscr.com/ni57ba